# Call method on multiple instances in Python

Tags: python

Is there something like this:

```
a,b,c = a,b,c.method()
```

?

It's just an example, I want to know the shortest way to do this

Comment: Well, is `a,b,c = (x.method() for x in (a,b,c))` good enough?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to return the results of calling `method()` on each object back into the objects themselves?

Comment: Why not use lists? `l2 = [x.method() for x in l1]` might be a good way to do what you need.

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly that short, but if I understand you correct, this will work:

```
a, b, c = (x.method() for x in (a, b, c))
```

(Note, that if `a`, `b` or `c` are referring to the same object, the method will be called few times).

Answer (score 6):

Not short. But here's an alternative using [`operator.methodcaller`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller).

```
a, b, c = map(operator.methodcaller('method'), (a,b,c))
```

Example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> a, b, c = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
>>> a, b, c = map(operator.methodcaller('pop'), (a,b,c))
>>> a
3
>>> b
6
>>> c
9

>>> m = operator.methodcaller('pop') # If you call `method` multiple times,
                                     #   keep a reference to the methodcaller
>>> a, b, c = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
>>> a, b, c = map(m, (a,b,c))
>>> a
3
>>> b
6
>>> c
9
```

If all objects are same type, you can use unbound method. For example `a`, `b`, `c` here all list instances. So you can use `list.pop` instead of `operator.methodcaller('pop')`.

For example:

```
>>> a, b, c = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] # a, b, c are all `list` objects.
>>> a, b, c = map(list.pop, (a,b,c))
>>> a
3
>>> b
6
>>> c
9
```

Comment: `__neg__` is not a so good example - one would better use `operator.neg` in this case. Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: Oops!! `a, b, c = map(list.pop, (a, b, c))` is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator would be the simplest way. For example, if a, b, and c were strings:

```
a, b, c = 'asdf', 'quer', 'zxcv'
```

And you wanted to capitalize the beginning of each string, you can do:

```
a, b, c = (x.capitalize() for x in (a, b, c))
```

Comment: This method is already suggested by bereal. Please do not duplicate the answer without providing additional information.

Comment: Sorry. Everyone please look in the comments of the original question for a generalized solution by bereal